# Which Event call on Clear Shopping Cart Button Magento

Tags: magento

I want to call event/observer when user click on "clear shopping cart button" which perform some action on database. i search a lot but didn't find any specific solution.
please anyone will give me the solution that Which event is calling on clear shopping cart button in magento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_updatePost`.

And your config.xml file should be,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_ModuleName>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packagename_ModuleName>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <modulename>
        <class>Packagename_ModuleName_Helper</class>
      </modulename>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <modulename>
        <class>Packagename_ModuleName_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </modulename>
    </models>
    <events>
      <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_updatePost> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_updatePost_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>modulename/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>clearCart</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_updatePost_handler>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_updatePost>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

And Model/Observer.php :

```
 <?php
    class Packagename_ModuleName_Model_Observer
    {

                public function clearCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
                {

//execute only in empty the cart function(all items removed )
    $updateAction = (string)Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('update_cart_action'); if ($updateAction != 'empty_cart') return;

                        echo "got it"; exit;

                 //your stuffs goes here.
                }

    }
```

**Note:** It is not triggered when we clear single cart (product) item . I tested it in my localserver and it is working fine.

Comment: It's a good answer. However this will be triggered every time the shopping cart is updated (so also when the quantity is updated for example). If you want it to be executed *only* when they try to empty the cart, add the following at the top of the clearCart function :         `$updateAction = (string)Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('update_cart_action');

            if ($updateAction != 'empty_cart') return; `

Comment: Thanks  Mayers Dev. You are right..! Tariq please accept my answer if you think if it worth. So it will help somebody.